# Why is the content of /run/resolvconf/interface/NetworkManager changed every time I reboot?

Tags: network-manager, dns, resolvconf

I have some issue with my dns configuration, so I googled and picked up a solution by **1)** editing `/run/resolvconf/interface/NetworkManager` and **2)**  running `sudo resolvconf -u`.

This helped a little bit, but the change of dns is not permanent, because I noticed that the dns I added to `/run/resolvconf/interface/NetworkManager` always get lost in it after a reboot, and my dns would be reversed as before, which is simply `127.0.0.1`, the original one.

So why the content of `/run/resolvconf/interface/NetworkManager` is changed? Or what's the mechanism behind its change?

Comment: @jdthood didn't think it's a good idea to edit `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` http://bit.ly/1KDG8vq   I assume that's because it breaks the "pointer" logic of `127.0.0.1` in `/etc/resolv.conf`, which is used to call the specific dns configured for different connection in NetworkManager. But I'm not so sure about the assumption of this logic. For me Linux is a maze..

Answer (score 3):

> The /run mountpoint is supposed to be a tmpfs mounted during early
>   boot, available and writable to for all tools at any time during
>   bootup.

What does this mean?

This means /run is tmpfs which means data on it is not a permanent  storage, it looks like the /tmp, so you can depend on saving any data there since this dir will completely wiped with another data during booting. For that you are loosing your configuration everytime.

Please take a look in this [Why has /var/run been migrated to /run?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57297/why-has-var-run-been-migrated-to-run)

Now for you, just add nameserver in  the `/etc/network/interfaces`

`dns-nameservers 127.0.0.1`

read this [Adding nameserver in resolv.conf](https://askubuntu.com/questions/324884/adding-nameserver-in-resolv-conf)

Else you can  put it in  `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base`

read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128220/how-do-i-set-my-dns-on-ubuntu-14-04) for more information